# split mp4-videos with ffmpeg as acurate as possible

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I'm trying to split a mp4-Video (Video-codec: h264 Audio-codec: mp3) with ffmpeg.
I know there are many other Threads here with similar issues but in my case I'm trying to be as accurate as possible. My first command was    `ffmpeg -ss <starttime> -i <input-file.mp4> -to <duration> -c copy <out-file.mp4>`
As I lernt about the issue with the Keyframes I created a command like this    `ffmpeg -ss <starttime> -i <input-file.mp4> -to <duration> -acodec copy -vcodec h264 <out-file.mp4>`
As I've seen in some Forums it is possible to handle the keyframe-issue by inserting manually Keyframes but I've found nothing about how exactly this could be done and weather it really helps.?
And how exact could it become if I re-encode the whole thing like in my second command and do I need to re-encode the audio Stream too?

EDIT: Or is it better to use the trim filter?

PS.:As I'm new to this network I hope not to have created a duplicate and to have it sorted into the right section.  (And apologize my English skills)

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -ss <starttime> -i <input-file.mp4> -t <duration> -acodec copy -vcodec h264 <out-file.mp4>`

Comment: Tried it but after merging the Videos with concat (I'm trying to remove advertises out of a video) at the beginning of an new "clip" the audio starts earlier while the Video hold the last Frame of the previous "clip" then a moment later it continuous as it should